# Where does tamper data extract the password string from?

Tags: network

I tried to login into Gmail account keeping the tamper data on. I just want to know from where does the tamper data get these field values. Is it stored anywhere in the cookies temp data. Where is the form POST data stored?

For example, the encrypted password string is shown in the tamper data field fldpassword. So from where does the tamper data get this field value. where is it stored on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data is sent in the body of the HTTP request.

```
POST /foo.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 28

username=bar&password=foobar
```

It is not "stored" anywhere. It is either constructed in the browser when Submit is clicked on a `<form />` tag with attribute `method="post"`, or it is generated when JavaScript code tells the browser to send such a request.

Similarly, on the server-side the server application itself decides what to do with this POST data.

Answer (score 2):

Tamperdata intercepts POST and GET traffic. If this is a POST request, then it is stored in a form as hidden attribute, or it is generated with an XHR request. Either way the client initiates the action, and tamperdata hook in on the calls.